# error al almacenar datos [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, express, cors

subi mi api rest a un hosting pero no quiere almacenar datos desde el hosting y tampoco quiere agarrar en otros dispositivos, solo agarra en el dispositivo en donde se creo todo, los datos se suben en studio 3t con base de datos mongo db, el hosting es
https://arq-serv-nube-servicioparahorarios.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Si quieres que te podamos ayudar no necesitamos ver tu hosting, necesitamos ver tu código. De qué sirve saber la URL (ignorando el hecho de que visitar url desconocidas y poco confiables es una de las mejores maneras de infectarse uno de virus poco apetecibles y una práctica muy poco recomendable) si no podemos ver qué estás haciendo y cómo lo estás haciendo?? No somos ordenadores, no debugamos el código viendo lo que genera. Debugamos el código VIENDO EL MISMO y analizándolo. Por favor utiliza el enlace [edit] para proporcionar un [mre] o al menos el código que genera el problema.